# What tense should we use to talk about the habits of a dead person?

Tags: grammar, past-tense

Is it correct to say: *"Franklin used to wake up early to read and write"*?

Franklin is dead and I'm talking about his daily habits. So, what tense should I use?

Comment: That sentence is fine.

Comment: It depends on whether the historical narrator places himself in the time of the subject he's writing about or in present time of his own writing.

Answer (score 4):

**What you have written is perfectly correct.**

But to summarise, the tense used for describing the life of a deceased will depend on whether you are recording a specific event, something that took place over time, or something habitual.

Lets say I was writing a biography of the English footballer - Stanley Matthews. I might say the following.

**Specific event in the simple past**:

*In 1953 Stanley Matthews was the hero of the Cup Final in which Blackpool beat Bolton 4-3.*

**Something that relates to a period of time - the imperfect**:

*Between 1932 and 1947 Matthews was playing regularly for Stoke City*

**For habitual matters - the modal *would*, or *used to***:

*When he was a boy Matthews would/used to practise dribbling with a tennis ball, around obstacles in the back garden of his home*.

Comment: Not disagreeing, but ´Between 1932 and 1947, Matthews played regularly for Stoke City.´ is also correct.

Comment: @TheNate Ok. Good point. So how about: *By 1936 he was playing regularly for Stoke*. If you agree, I will edit my answer, and also make the point that nothing changes when a person dies - as seemed to be implied in the question. It would make no difference were the person still alive, as to which past verb-form to use.

Comment: Thomas Jefferson has visited Paris.